# Push Notification on ios is coming when it is turned off

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

My team and I developed an android and iOS social App and we are using firebase for push notification. On iOS when the notification is turned off in the app, we are still getting the notification ring. For example, we are getting the message from other users. However, on Android, it seems to be working fine.

Comment: Can share your code for push notification permission?

Comment: Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your question to include what you have already tried and where you think the problem might be. Also code would be helpful here

Comment: Thank you for the guide. This is my first here using this service so I am learning how this platform works.